# Symfony2 Gregwar / CaptchaBundle Fatal error

Tags: symfony, captcha

I did all steps from

```
https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle
```

Added to composer.json and updated, config.yml enabled the bundle  But I get fatal error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\GregwarCaptchaBundle' not found in /var/www/Surgery/app/AppKernel.php on line 26 Call Stack: 0.0000 228784 1. {main}() /var/www/Surgery/web/app_dev.php:0 0.0037 1211816 2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /var/www/Surgery/web/app_dev.php:25 0.0037 1212000 3. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /var/www/Surgery/app/bootstrap.php.cache:614 0.0037 1212160 4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles() /var/www/Surgery/app/bootstrap.php.cache:569 0.0037 1212864 5. AppKernel->registerBundles() /var/www/Surgery/app/bootstrap.php.cache:797
```

I have little problems after update my ubuntu. I' using sf 2.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Symfony2.1. I did **composer install**. I noted that in my output console there was not captcha bundle installed. I fixed the problem with 
    **composer update**

Answer (score 0):

In case of somebody bumped into my (similar to this one) problem.

I took code from https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle and did all steps (downloaded by `git clone`). I put the code into `\vendor\bundles\Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\`

Finally when i got an error

> Error: Class 'Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder' not found in
>   D:...\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line
>   1598

i downloaded another code from https://github.com/Gregwar/Captcha/ and put it into `\vendor\bundles\Gregwar\Captcha\`

and everything went ok. Hope this will help anybody